# Solve for the reflection coefficient in terms of $\beta$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, physics, reflection

In a previous part, I solved for $B$ in terms of $A$ and resulted in this:

$$B = \frac{i\beta}{(1-i\beta)}A$$

Now I need to find $R=\frac{|B|^2}{|A|^2}$. To do so, I did this:

$$\frac{B}{A}=\frac{i\beta}{(1-i\beta)}$$
$$\frac{|B|^2}{|A|^2}=\frac{(i\beta)^2}{((1-i\beta))^2}$$
$$\frac{|B|^2}{|A|^2}=\frac{-\beta^2}{1-2i\beta-\beta ^2}$$
$$\frac{|B|^2}{|A|^2}=\frac{\beta^2}{\beta ^2+2i\beta - 1}$$
$$\frac{|B|^2}{|A|^2}=\frac{\beta^2}{\beta + i}$$

...but the book continues the example to say that it's actually 
$$R=\frac{\beta^2}{1+\beta^2}$$

Where did I make a mistake? This is from *Introduction to Quantum Mechanics* by David Griffiths (1st edition I think), pg. 57.

Comment: This part is wrong $$\frac{|B|^2}{|A|^2}=\frac{(i\beta)^2}{((1-i\beta))^2}$$ You need to take absolute value of the right hand side and then square, not just square it

Comment: @YuriyS That was it. I forgot to take the absolute value for complex numbers. Feel free to write it as an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part is wrong

$$\frac{|B|^2}{|A|^2}=\frac{(i\beta)^2}{((1-i\beta))^2}$$

You need to take absolute value of the right hand side and then square, not just square it. (Read about complex numbers, and what is the absolute value of a complex number. You need to find the real part and the imaginary part of the expression on the right hand side. )